# Resource temporarily unavailable ttyS3

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty

I have a embedded system with serial configured as ttyS3,I'm trying to start getty using

```
`/sbin/getty -L ttyS3 115200 vt100 -H HOME -u root -a`
```

but its failed to start session with login after that I have tried

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS3
cat: can't open '/dev/ttyS3': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

but I'm getting error like '/dev/ttyS3': Resource temporarily unavailable,so is there any way to find out which process is using this resource (/dev/ttyS3)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `lsof` - it lists all the open files. For your purpose do the following -

```
        lsof /dev/ttyS3
```

this will show which process holds up this resource.