# mmap() Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: memory, memory-management, kernel-module, mmap

I am trying to implement a memory management kernel module. This module uses `mmap()` system call. After implementation, I tried calling mmap which gives me an error `Resource temporarily unavailable`
I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162943/resource-temporarily-unavailable-ttys3) thread. The solution does not work in my case.

Here is the kernel implementation:- Excluding variable declarations.

```
kmalloc_ptr = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL)
static int simple_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
 remap = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, (virt_to_phys)(kmalloc_ptr) >> 12,
                vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                vma->vm_page_prot)
        return -EAGAIN;
```

value in `remap` is 0

Comment: Could you please provide the full snippet? You see - there is a typo (`kAmlloc_ptr`); also, missing semicolon at the end of `remap_pfn_range()`, and no `if` statement - I mean, `return -EAGAIN` is done in any case.

Also, despite the fact that `pfn` argument is calculated right way, it's so bizarre that you calculate it based on `kmalloc_ptr`. Why do you need to allocate some kernel memory here at all? You are expected to use `vma->vm_pgoff` here instead of `(virt_to_phys)(kamlloc_ptr) >> 12`. So, please also show the rest of the code.

Comment: @DaanGerlach I just figured that the problem was with the `return EAGAIN` without the if statement. The error is resolved now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Also,  you'd better use `PAGE_SHIFT` instead of the magic number (`12`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, I was not something wrong with the the mapping as I had suspected.

The error was remap should be used as

```
`if ((remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, (unsigned long long)(virt_to_phys((void *)mapped_data)) >> PAGE_SHIFT, size, vma->vm_page_prot))
return -EAGAIN`;
```